# How to get the first x (leftmost) digits of a decimal number

Tags: c, numbers

Let's assume that I have `n=1234` and I want to get the first `x` digits of `n`. Assume `x=2`, in C math I just compute `1234/100` and I will get `12`. But how can I do it programatically? I.e., using math.
I have implemented it by the horrible way, converting to string and putting a `0` at `x` position.
If possible, I want to avoid built-in C functions because my goal is to convert the algorithm to assembly language later.

Comment: What's the problem, using directly `1234/100` (dividing) on the numbers?

Comment: @KirilKirov The problem is that `12/100` will NOT give you the first two digits.

Comment: Up to which number of digits the solution shall work?

Comment: Divide by 10 until the result is small enough?

Answer (score 4):

Without using any library functions, the best way to do it is with brute force. The maximum value an integer can take is 2147483648 so we won't deal with anything over that.

```
int first_two(int value)
{
    assert(value >= 0);  // unspecified for negative numbers
    if (value >= 1000000000)
        return value / 100000000;
    if (value >= 100000000)
        return value / 10000000;
    if (value >= 10000000)
        return value / 1000000;
    if (value >= 1000000)
        return value / 100000;
    if (value >= 100000)
        return value / 10000;
    if (value >= 10000)
        return value / 1000;
    if (value >= 1000)
        return value / 100;
    if (value >= 100)
        return value / 10;
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Nice optimisation. For mega-optimisation I suggest turning it into a binary search tree; `if < 1000000 { if < 1000 { if < 100 ... else ... } else ... }`. It's the egg-dropping problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it programmatically by taking the floor of the decimal logarithm of your number (in case of 1234, it's `floor(3.091315)`, which is 3), adding one, and subtracting `n` - the desired number of decimal digits. This would give you `x` such that integer-dividing the original value by `10^x` gives you the desired result:

```
#include <math.h>
...
int num = 12345;
int n = 3;
int log10 = (log(num)/log(10))+1;
int divisor = pow(10, log10-n);
int res = num / divisor;
printf("%d\n", res);
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/XrQPWx).

Converting the above to assembly would be tricky because of the math functions involved. You can simplify it by defining a table of powers of ten, searching it for the first item that's greater than or equal to the desired number (giving you `log10` above) and then grabbing the `log10-n`-th entry, giving you `pow(10, log10-n)`:

```
int pow10[] = {1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000, 1000000000};

int main(void) {
    int num = 12345;
    int n = 3;
    int log10 = 0;
    while (pow10[log10] < num) {
        log10++;
    }
    int divisor = pow10[log10-n];
    int res = num / divisor;
    printf("log10(num)+1=%d, divisor=%d, result=%d\n", log10, divisor, res);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is [the modified demo](http://ideone.com/h90Itk).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following algorithm: keep divide the `n` per `10` till you get `n < 10^x`

here after the code

```
int power10(int x) {
    int p = 1;
    while (x) {
        p *= 10;
        x--;
    }
    return p;
}

int main (void) {

    int x = 2;
    int n = 1234;
    int max = power10(x);

    int res = n;   
    while(res>=max)
        res = res/10;

   printf("%d\n",res);
}
```

Comment: I think you want `res>=max`, otherwise e.g. `100` will result in 3 digits.

Comment: @MarkRansom indeed. I updated the answer. thanks for the remark

Answer (score 1):

```
int getLeftDigits(double num, double numOfDigits)
{
double divider = pow(10, numOfDigits);

if (num < divider)
    return num;

getLeftDigits(num/10, numOfDigits);
}
```

If you want to avoid the use of the pow function, you can just implement it by yourself as shown in one of the other comments here.